# Cakephp Site Root with username conflict with controllers

Tags: cakephp, controller, routes, url-routing

I got this code working.
when i go to **domain.com/** it will route to home->index(). when i type in **domain.com/username**.. it will route to users->view(username)

file: config/routes.php

```
$controllerList = App::objects('Controller'); 

foreach($controllerList as $controller)
{
    $controllerName = str_replace('Controller', '', $controller);
    if($controllerName != "App" & $controllerName != "Pages")
    {
        Router::connect('/' . $controllerName . '/:action/*', array('controller' => $controllerName));

        $firstLetterLower = strtolower(substr($controllerName,0,1));
        $lowerCaseName = $firstLetterLower . substr($controllerName,1);

        Router::connect('/' . $lowerCaseName . '/:action/*', array('controller' => $lowerCaseName));

    }
}
Router::connect('/:username', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'views'), array('pass' => array('username')));
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index'));
```

the problem is that i cannot route my controllers domain.com/controller without putting the action..

This will work: **domain.com/blog/index**, **domain.com/forum/index**, **domain.com/users/login**

This wont work: **domain.com/blog** it will be treated as username

Answer (score 0):

Exclude the controller names from being matched in the username route. You should have a list of them to prevent people from registering with these names at all.

Comment: I edited the post.. got the code for traversing available controllers.. still it will treat it as username....

Answer (score 0):

Put you code like this. this will not treat blog as username

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/blog', array('controller' => 'blog', 'action' => 'index'));
Router::connect('/:username', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'views'), array('pass' => array('username')));
```

Thanks..!